# Showing different masks for loading grids asynchronously - EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I have multiple grids which are being loaded asynchronously, is there way to show multiple masking messages for each grid. Right now I have this code to show the message

```
 loadText = 'Searching sentry Data...';
//Use the mask function on the Ext.getBody() element to mask the body element during Ajax calls
    Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest',function(){Ext.getBody().mask(loadText, 'loading').setHeight(Ext.getBody().getHeight());}, Ext.getBody());
    Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete',Ext.getBody().unmask ,Ext.getBody());
    Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', Ext.getBody().unmask , Ext.getBody());
```

I have added the code to add a mask in the load function of the store but I think only one modal can be shown.

Answer (score 0):

using loadMask:true on the grid works